# ES6 Vue and Webpack project doesn't run on IE11 but works on Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, webpack, vue.js

I am writing a project with ES6+vue+webpack. Currently the project can run in Chrome, but when it run the same in IE11, it has some problems and doesn't run as expected. It throws the following error. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

The error tips is :

`if (!canWriteStorage(storage)) {throw new Error('Invalid storage instance given');}`

I didn't write this method, so what could have gone wrong?

Comment: obviously `canWriteStorage(storage)` returns false ... so your code throws an error as expected

Comment: Sorry, it's hard to help without a bit more context. Can you edit your post to contain more of the code? Where is the `storage` variable declared?

Comment: IE11, and edge, and firefox [never supported WebSQL](https://caniuse.com/#search=websql). Could that be your problem ? A quick check in chrome devtools, application tab, WebSQL, will show you if anything is being written there.

Answer (score 0):

Vue supports IE11, just with one exception - promises. Add promise polyfill to assets. I am using ES6 Promise (https://github.com/stefanpenner/es6-promise). And, of course, you must transpile your code, IE11 does not supports ES6. Use Babel with webpack. And if you are using fetch, not Axios, use fetch polyfill... Thats all, I think. Your app will run on IE11. In the end, with all these polyfills and transpilation, maybe you can target it for IE10 also...